# How to detect zoom level with javascript on android 2.2 browser

Tags: javascript, android, zooming

I have seen multiple examples for how to detect zoom level for desktop browsers, but I can't seem to find how to do it for android 2.2 browser.

This example works fine for chrome in desktop:

```
   function detectZoom() {
    var screenCssPixelRatio = (window.outerWidth - 8) / window.innerWidth;
    zoomLevel = 0;

    if (screenCssPixelRatio >= .46 && screenCssPixelRatio <= .54) {
      zoomLevel = "-4";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= .64) {
      zoomLevel = "-3";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= .76) {
      zoomLevel = "-2";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= .92) {
      zoomLevel = "-1";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= 1.10) {
      zoomLevel = "0";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= 1.32) {
      zoomLevel = "1";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= 1.58) {
      zoomLevel = "2";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= 1.90) {
      zoomLevel = "3";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= 2.28) {
      zoomLevel = "4";
    } else if (screenCssPixelRatio <= 2.70) {
      zoomLevel = "5";
    } else {
      zoomLevel = "0";
    }

    return zoomLevel;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I can say that this isn't working because of how Android handles `window.innerWidth` (see this quirksmode post: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html#t01).  If I find a solution, I'll be sure to share it.